# Migrate from another server: Why CakePHP show's page not found?

Tags: php, cakephp, migration, migrate

**TLDR:**

Recently migrated my site to a new host.  The header and footer (without CSS) show up, but the pages all show "Page Not Found".

**Further Explanation:**

I migrated my site (small CakePHP project) to a new host, and did these steps:
And follow this steps:

1. Migrated every file and folder
2. Imported the complete database
3. Changed the database configuration
4. Checked the folders, everything is set to dirname, and stuff like that, so no problem

Now, when I access the site in the new hosting, it shows page not found, and the CSS are missing.  I edited the `index.php` on `app/webroot` and added a few echos to see if the flow was ok.  If I add an echo, the CSS works (if I add echos in any part of the source, the echo was echo '1';) but still with the "Page Not Found".

Comment: Have you copied the .htaccess files as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of CakePHP are you using? If it is 2.x, you need to make sure you have php 5.2.8 or greater.

The other thing to confirm is that `mod_rewrite` is enabled and working correctly. It sounds like this may be the issue.

Comment: Hi Chuck, thanks for the answer, and sorry for the late response to answer the answer to my question
php 5.3.10
cake 0.2.9
mod_rewrite is aparently enabled (godaddy is checking it anyway, thats my new host) 

I would like to repeat that the site is kind of working, but is like is not showing the css (except if i add an echo '1'; on the index file) and doesn't know what page to show so always showing page not found :S

Comment: Can you provide the header information from your layout file? Also what version of cake php?

Comment: Like I said before, my expertice with cake is none, I'm trying to learn, and to learn the best way is to work with a real proyect, but unfortunately I have no idea where to find the header information of my layout field :P.
If I go to the folder  cake, and read the file version.txt it says 1.3.8

Comment: Look in the app/views/layout directory. You should see `default.ctp` or some other layout file there.

Comment: Hi Chuck, sorry for the long delay and I'm really thanked that you answered me =),
I rechecked twice, it have a lot of codes, which part would you like to know?

Comment: Aditional information, I tryed print_r($this); on the main object that have the html, and the css is empty

Comment: Is the main HTML loading? What do you see when you run the site?

Comment: Like I said =) I see the header, the footer (no css) and page not found in the body

Comment: How can you see the header and footer of your code and 'page not found'? Is the header and the footer your header and footer or default header/footer for a 404?

Comment: It's like the cake is working, but instead of going to index is showing header and footer, and page not found, if I go to policies it show header and footer page not found :S

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing more we can do to help you trouble shoot unless you provide some code (.htaccess, layout file, etc). Consider using pastebin and adding links to your original post.

Comment: Thanks Chuck for everything, I will close this question, and try to find the people that was in charge before me =)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to copy any of the .htaccess files.